# decompress split zip files (with zipsplit) in one shot

Tags: zip, unzip

I'm using the split feature of zip (zipsplit) on very large files (300GB).

```
file_parts.z01  
file_parts.z02  
file_parts.z03  
file_parts.z04  
file_parts.z05  
file_parts.zip
```

Then to extract the content, the current solution is:

```
zip -s 0 file_parts.zip --out recombined.zip
unzip recombined.zip
```

However, it's very slow because it requires a lot of I/O to write the final zip file to disk.

How to recombine the split files and unzip in one shot, without writing the recombined split file on disk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

one can directly unzip the last file:

```
unzip file_parts.zip
```

7z can also unzip multi-part zip archives.

```
7z x file_parts.zip
```